# Changing  the inner HTML in a SimpleModal dialog?

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I'm using the beforeSubmit function of the jQuery form pluggin in order to  close a modal dialog, and I want another one to popup after-wards with the result of the form being submitted, so I put another modal in the success function and passing through the responseText... but the new modal dialog never pops up... how can I get it to pop up? I would also like to know how to change the innerHTML of the dialog box. I tried dialog.data.html(responseText); and some other stuff, but none of it worked.

Here's the code for the form submit:

```
$('#member_ban_forum').ajaxForm( { 
    data: { member: member }, beforeSubmit: function() { 
        $.modal.close();
    },

    success: function (responseText) {
        $().delay(5000, function () {
            simpleModal(responseText);
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the code for the simpleModal popup function I made:

```
function simpleModal ( html ) {
    $(html).modal({
        containerCss:{
            height:340,
            width:450
        },

        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn(350, function () {
                dialog.container.fadeIn(350, function () {
                    dialog.data.slideDown(350);
                });
            });
        },

        onClose: function (dialog) {
            dialog.data.slideUp(350, function () {
                dialog.container.fadeOut(350, function () {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeOut(350, function () {
                        $.modal.close();
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: highlight the entire code block and click the `{}` button to space it over 4 spaces...which enabled markdown code formatting :)

Comment: Yea, sorry, first time posting on stack overflow. Also the first time in a while I haven't been able to use google to find the answer to a problem :(

Comment: ur code will scare anyone away..

Comment: Already fixed it -_- Should be nicely spaced and such now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think the problem is with your use of `delay()`.

The following works for me:

```
$('#member_ban_forum').ajaxForm( { 
    data: { member: member },
    beforeSubmit: function() { 
        $.modal.close();
    },
    success: function (responseText) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            simpleModal(responseText);
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yea, that's how I ended up repairing this problem, I also ended up changing the HTMl in the div with the "simplemodal-wrap" class. Is there anyother way of changing the content thats in the modal?